# Installing Hue on top of standalone Hadoop 2.5.1

Tags: hadoop, hue

I am trying to get Hue working on top of a standalone Hadoop 2.5.1 (Ubuntu 14.04) and am running into issues when running the server.  I followed this tutorial: http://gethue.com/how-to-build-hue-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty/.

When trying to wget `http://localhost:8000` I get:

```
hduser@ip-172-31-11-6:~/hue$ wget localhost:8000
--2014-11-01 00:40:45--  http://localhost:8000/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 FOUND
Location: http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/?next=/ [following]
--2014-11-01 00:40:45--  http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/?next=/
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
2014-11-01 00:40:45 ERROR 500: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.
```

It's a single node cluster and hdfs is running on port 54310.  The Hadoop user is hduser.  I've looked all over for info regarding this issue and can't come up with much of anything.

Any ideas of what could be going wrong, or how I could further debug this issue?

Best,

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Blah!  It was a database connection permission issue.  I'm just using the SQLite version and the user I was starting the web server with didn't have access.  Changing the owner of /hue/desktop/desktop.db to the same user that I'm running the web server on worked.

New issues, but that's better than nothing.  This is the solution to the 500 error anyway.